# A chess player, X, plays a series of games against an opponent, Y

Tags: probability

A chess player $X$ plays a series of games against an opponent $Y$. For each game, the probability that $X$ wins is $p$, independently of the results of other games. If $X$ plays 4 games against $Y$, show that the probability that this series of games contains at least 2 consecutive wins by $X$ is $p^2(3-2p)$.

I know this can be done by listing all the possible ways and then summing the probabilities, but is there another way of doing this?

Comment: You mentioned that you tried writing down all the possible outcomes in which $X$ has at least 2 consecutive wins, but you're not sure you got them all. How about if you just write down ALL the possible outcomes (how many are there total?), then put a mark by those outcomes in which $X$ has at least two consecutive wins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generalize, let $p_n$ be the probability that player $1$ wins at least $2$ games when $n$ games are played. Then,
$$
p_n=(1-p)p_{n-1}+(1-p)^2p_{n-2}+p^2, \quad p_2 =p^2, \quad p_3=2p^2-p^3
$$
From here you can find any $p_n$ by recursively substituting in.... alternatively, an exact solution can be found by standard methods that solve the cubic equation,
$$
0=x^3+(p-2)x^2+p(p-1)x+(1-p)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is simpler ...

You want all cases with a "WW" in them.  e.g. WWLL, WWWL, etc.  Let "A" mean either win or lose Prob(A)=1 of course.  The cases are:

WWAA:   $p^2$  
LWWA:   $(1-p) \times p^2$ 
ALWW:   $(1-p) \times p^2$

$= 3 p^2 -2 p^3$ 
$= p^2 (3 -2 p)$

Note - to avoid counting cases twice, I listed the cases by doing the WW moving from left to right, allowing anything to the right of the WW *but* no '2 consecutive wins' to the left of the WW.

---

For a larger number of games, this method is much better than the basic method, e.g. for 6 games, the answer would be:

WWAAAA:  $p^2$  
LWWAAA:  $(1-p) \times p^2$  
ALWWAA:  $(1-p) \times p^2$  
XXLWWA:  $(1-P_2) \times (1-p) \times p^2$ 
XXXLWW:  $(1-P_3) \times (1-p) \times p^2$

where $P_2 = p^2$ is the probability of having at least 2 consecutive wins in 2 games, and $P_3 = p^2 (2-p)$ is the probability of having at least 2 consecutive wins in 3 games.

$P(6) = 5 p^2 -4 p^3 -3 p^3 +4 p^5 -p^6$

---

The general answers are:

$P_2 = p^2$ 
$P_3 = 2 p^2 -p^3$ 
$P_4 = 3 p^2 -2 p^3$ 
$P_5 = 4 p^2 -3 p^3 -p^4 +p^5$ 
$P_6 = 5 p^2 -4 p^3 -3 p^4 +4 p^5 -p^6$ 
$P_7 = 6 p^2 -5 p^3 -6 p^4 +9 p^5 -3 p^6$ 
$P_8 = 7 p^2 -6 p^3 -10 p^4 +16 p^5 -5 p^6 -2 p^7 +p^8$ 
$P_9 = 8 p^2 -7 p^3 -15 p^4 +25 p^5 -6 p^6 -9 p^7 +6 p^8 -p^9$ 
$P_{10} = 9 p^2 -8 p^3 -21 p^4 +36 p^5 -5 p^6 -24 p^7 +18 p^8 -4 p^9$

There are some patterns to the coefficients of $P_n$ e.g. the $p^2$, $p^3$, $p^4$ coefficients, but I have not found a pattern for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really that tedious?

The cases are: 
4 wins:  $1 \times p^4$ 
1 loss, can happen in 4 ways:  $4 \times p^3 (1-p)$ 
2 wins if WWLL or LWWL or LLWW, so can happen in 3 ways:  $3 \times p^2 (1-p)^2$

$p^4  +(4 p^3 -4 p^4) +(3 p^2 -6 p^3 +3 p^4)$  
$= -2 p^3 +3 p^2$ 
$= p^2 (3 -2 p)$

Comment: I'll edit the question. Is there another way to do this?